# Difference between preview and deploy result rectangle

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a display difference when I deploy my report from  what I can see in the Preview.

My report is composed of rectangles with elements inside (textbox, indicators, etc.). On the top there is a white rectangle which the size is the same as the body. The background of the body is a light blue. It should appears like this:

[image]

But when I deploy it, it appears like this:

[image]

There is a strange space between the top rectangle and the end of the body.
I am using Chrome. On Firefox, the space between the white rectangle and the end of the body is smaller but still exists.

The rectangle hasn't any border. Here are his properties:

[image]

For the body, I even tried with a white border to hide:
[image]

This is the property of the report:

[image]

I also tried with a table instead of the top white rectangle but I have the same result.

Comment: Dumb question but when you are in PREVIEW -  do you click Print Layout as well, as to see what the report will actually look like when it is printed? (the button located next to the Print button, in preview)

Comment: When I click Print Layout, the report looks exactly how I would like, so the same as in the Preview. Any idea?